# How do I extract the value of 'temp' from a nested JSON payload in Node-red?

Tags: javascript, json, node-red

`{"rssi":-46,"message":"{\"temp\":55,\"hum\":88,\"moist\":50}"}`

In the above payload, I can extract the value of `rssi` using the following code in Node-red.

```
p = JSON.parse(msg.payload);
node.log(typeof p);
msg.payload = p.rssi;
return msg;
```

But how do I extract the value of `temp` from this.

Comment: After the first line there's no "JSON" involved. `p` is just a plain old object.

Comment: [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects)

Comment: If you have a saying payload like that in future, rather than having `JSON.parse()` in a function node, you can always pass the object through the JSON node

Answer (score 0):

There is a colon missing in the source json. It should be

> {"rssi":-46,"snr":{"temp":55,"hum":88,"moist":55}"}

Like @Andreas mentioned, after first line its all about accessing the object "p".

You should be able to access the temp using

```
msg.payload=p.snr.temp;
```

Comment: I corrected the missing colon in my post. I tried your suggestion, but the debug message says "undefined". Any other suggestion please.

Comment: Have you tried changing `sni` to `message` as in the example in the question?

Comment: "msg.payload=p.snr.temp" is not working in Node_red and debug says undefined payload.